# Magento 2 : How to Add wysiwyg Editor in Frontend Custom Form

Tags: magento2, frontend, forms, custom-field

I wanted to create WYSIWYG editor in custom form frontend.

What I tried doing is :

1. Created `WysiwygConfig.php` file inside `Vendor/Extension/Plugin` directory with code :

   ```
   class WysiwygConfig {
       public function afterGetConfig($subject, \Magento\Framework\DataObject $config)
       {
           $styleArray = [
               'Hero - Image' => 'hero__image',
               'Hero - Heading' => 'hero__heading',
               'Hero - Action Button' => 'hero__primary-action'
           ];

           $styles = array_map(function($title, $class) {
               return "{$title}={$class}; ";
           }, array_keys($styleArray), array_values($styleArray));

           $config->addData(["settings" => ["theme_advanced_styles" => implode("; ", $styles)]]);

           return $config;
       }
   }
   ?>
   ```
2. Created `di.xml` file inside `Vendor/Extension/etc/` folder and provided plugin name with type.
3. I have frontend template where I want to implement WYSIWYG editor.

I had followed one tutorial but that one is incomplete for me. Please help me to do it.

Comment: Can you share what issue facing while you followed that link?

Comment: @Sagar: Please share the tutorial URL which you follow to add WYSIWYG editor in frontend form field. I also want to add WYSIWYG editor.